# function that recalls itself upon a catch of non-critical error

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I got a function named `inner_logic()` that can throw many types of exception , each of one of two types: `critical` and `non-critical`. The logic of `inner_logic()` includes an "infinite" loop, so in case of a non-critical exception I'd wish to step back in to it. At that point you can ask why not catching the non-critical exception within the loop, and the reason is that it's an abstract class with a few inheritors, each have a unique loop. for clarification, what I *want* to do is something like:

```
public void logic()
{
try
{
 inner_logic();
}
catch (non_critical e)
{
  // log 
  logic();
}
catch(critical e)
{
 // log 
 return;
}

public virtual void inner_logic(){}
```

As far as I can tell, I seems that it should work, and that all calls are "catchable", but it feels kinda hackish.

**My Question is**: Is there a better way for doing that, or a reason I should reconsider my suggestion?

Comment: Working code in [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) pls.

Comment: This in itself is an infinite loop, since non_critical errors may be thrown each time you call `inner_logic()`.

Comment: @SQB not really, there's a cancellation token involved. but good note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did something similar in the past. I try to avoid recursion so I did a loop instead.

```
public void logic()
{
    bool running = true;

    while(running)
    {
        running = false;

        try
        {
            inner_logic();
        }
        catch(non_critical e)
        {
            running = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, I did it a bit diffrently. Instead of a boolean, I counted the number of non_critical errors. If the number exceded 3 then I handled it as a critical error.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the recursion the first time around! A loop is definitely much better.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do it this way, as if the current state of the application means that the non- critical exception is thrown repeatedly, a stack overflow exception will occur.

Catch the exception outside the method and repeat if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It feels to me like it should just be looping:

```
while (true) // Or probably have a maximum number of retries
{
    try
    {
        // Logic

        // Break out of the loop by returning if we succeed
        return;
    }
    catch (NonCriticalException e)
    {
        // Log, then let the loop continue
    }
    catch (CriticalException e)
    {
        // Log, then rethrow (in preference to returning)
    }
}
```

With your original approach, if the non-critical exception just keeps happening, you'll get a `StackOverflowException`. I would definitely suggest adding a maximum retry count though. (Keeping track of the number of retries is good for logging, too.)